# How to use NOT IN Statement in Power BI case statements

Tags: powerbi

I am trying to write something like this in power BI using DAX and cant figure it out.
case when table.column_name NOT IN ( "I", "IP", "N", "T", "W",) THEN 1 END
any suggestions will be very appreaciated.